# Active selector on css doesn't work, but :hover work correctly

Tags: css, selector

Any one can help me?
whats wrong, my active selector doesn't work, but hover work correctly
when i clicked twice text change color, but icon not.
how to fix this problem?

/* Desktop Navigation */

```
.nav-menu {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #a8a9b4;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-menu a:active {
  color: #fefeff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
  color: #fefeff;
}

.nav-menu a i {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: #6f7180;
}

.nav-menu a:hover i {
  color: #149ddd;
}

.nav-menu a:active i {
  color: #149ddd;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your html and css to the code snippet?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to include the icon that you mention. Please include a full example of the problem in the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ..also `:active` may not mean what you think it does.

Comment: http://snippi.com/s/judjw0v